# What will be total number of solutions of $n_1a+n_2b+n_3c=n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

What will be total number of solutions of $n_1a+n_2b+n_3c=n$?

Here, $n_1,n_2,n_3,n$ are constants already provided in the question and $a,b,c$ are variables. What we have to do is find out the total number of solutions. Simpler version of this was for $n_1=n_2=n_3=1$, where we got it by formula: $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$. But what about this? And how can this be generalized for $m$ variables?

Comment: You should include the question in the body, and make it clear that the variables are naturals (integers?).  I don't believe there is a simple answer.

Comment: Why, exactly, is it urgent?

Comment: There is a generating functions approach. Nothing as simple as the formula when the $n_i$ are all $1$.

Comment: What is the domain of a,b,c? If real numbers are allowed, then there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that all variables are non-negative integers.

The best way to understand this is to use generating functions.
The generating function for your problem is
$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n s(n)
=\frac1{(1-x^a)(1-x^b)(1-x^c)}
$.

This was known in the 1800's and Hardy and Ramanujan used a generalization of this
to investigate partitions.

Essentially, for each of a, b, and c,
write $(1-x^k)$ as the product of k-th roots of unity,
expand by partial fractions,
and look at the resulting series.

In other words, it can be a mess.

Good luck.